# Is there a stable integration procedure/pluggin for Django 1.1 and Google app engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

What is the best procedure/plugging to use to integrate django and google app engine? I have read many articles in the internet and seen videos on how to go round this. Am still left wondering which is the best procedure to use.

Is there an official procedure documented in django or google app engine. Examples and site references will really help.

Am using Python 2.6, Django 1.1

Gath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO way you can run Python 2.6 on App Engine: it's 2.5 only.

If you're rarin' to have Django 1.1 (with Python 2.5), I suggest [app-engine patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) which now supports it (it's a release candidate, not a final release, but close). I find their docs good and thorough, and their code well written and solid.

Comment: Can i run python 2.5 and 2.6 on the same machine?

Comment: Yep, I do have several on my Mac for example: `which python2.5` is /usr/bin/python2.5 (Apple-supplied "system python), and `which python2.6` (& similarly for others) is /usr/local/bin/python2.6 (in my case `which python` is the 2.5 version for smoothest, simplest access to the App Engine - suitable Python;-). Coexistence is no problem, just pick which one you want as the single default "python" and use explicit version numbers in the command to access any of the others.